# google-places-apiI had a place id in my database which returns 0 result

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I had in my database the followings places id :

```
ChIJ4X4hzjm7rhIRVigYuqinSe4
ChIJmyWoeEEM5kcR_8LHmraJvOs
ChIJdXD8rrkM5kcRdynfSAYhm8E
```

But when i use the google service geocoding :

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-place-id?hl=fr

I am sure it was a valid place id.

I have no result, do you have a idea ?

Comment: I get a result for that placeId:  
ChIJu1PKTs445kcR53KxCVe1t8I, 
39 Avenue Léonard de Vinci, 95470 Fosses, France

Comment: Yes sorry it was the wrong placeid, i updated the question

Answer (score 0):

It is really difficult to address this question on StackOverflow, because you need access to internal Google database in order to investigate what happened with these place IDs.

I can see a couple of possible scenarios when this might happen that place ID stop working:

1. The place ID was marked as duplicate of another place ID, so it was merged with another feature and doesn't exist anymore
2. The place ID was flagged by users on maps.google.com or mobile app as wrong and was removed by Google team from the database (https://support.google.com/maps/answer/7084895).

In order to avoid these issues I would suggest storing place IDs along with an original query in your database. In this case if place ID that previously worked returns ZERO_RESULTS or NOT_FOUND you can rerun the original query and get an updated place ID.